# The type or namespace name 'IClientValidatable' could not be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a custom attribute in my asp.net MVC application using the following link:

http://www.falconwebtech.com/post/2012/04/18/MVC3-Custom-Validation-Attributes-for-Client-Server-Side-Validation-with-Unobtrusive-Ajax.aspx

but I am getting following errors:

Error   52  The type or namespace name 'IClientValidatable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   53  The type or namespace name 'ModelClientValidationRule' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
Error   54  The type or namespace name 'ModelMetadata' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
Error   55  The type or namespace name 'ControllerContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am using asp.net MVC 4 beta.

I tried to add reference of asp.net.MVC to the project but it is not available in add reference dialogue.

Please suggest how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have added `using System.Web.Mvc;` to the top of your file which is the namespace in which this class is defined.

Comment: Hi @Darin, It is not available in list. where to add this ?

Comment: To the top of your file. Where you are putting your `using` references. Also make sure that the `System.Web.Mvc` assembly is referenced in your project (when you create a new project it is added automatically) especially if you are trying to put this code in a class library or some other project type in which you forgot to reference it.

Comment: Hi @Darin: I am using this code in class library and I try to add reference of System.Web.MVC but it is not located in the popup in any tab like recent projects, .net componets and not in other.

Comment: Make sure that this class library is targetting the full .NET 4.0 framework and not the Client Profile. Then System.Web.Mvc will show in the Net tab.

Comment: For what it's worth now... I had to add a reference to System.Web.WebPages as well.